# NGG Gallery Wordpress - Blank page instead of 404

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, gallery

THe links to my NGG Gallery look something like this: 
www.mywebsite.com/photos/nggallery/album/gallername

As long as the first part, namely; "www.mywebsite.com/photos/nggallery" is correct it does not matter what the last part looks like. I can change the name of the album in the URL and it would direct me to a blank page with the title "photos", but without showing a 404 Error.

I would like to display a 404 instead of a blank page, since it does not show any information if the wrong URL is entered into the browser-bar.

Why is NGG behaving this way?

Answer (score -1):

NGG is a pile - It is buggy and conflicts with everything. Drop it.

If you need a gallery, use Galleria, which extends media library native gallery functions and will work without issues you mention, yet still have lightbox, etc.